# String with one character can be casted to char?

Tags: java, string, casting, char

```
String message = "a";
char message1 = (char) message;
System.out.println(message1);
```

Gives me an output error,

This should be converted with ease because the string is one character `"a"`

**I know I can do it explicitly sorry**, why the two are incompatible to cast if they are storing the same (only one character)?

Comment: "Does this should be converted with ease because the string is one character "a"?" Can you rewrite that question into a more understandable English? Are you asking "why can't `"a"` be converted to a `char`?" or "can `"a"` be converted to a `char`" or "how to convert `"a"` to a `char`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that. You can cast a `char` to `Character` because the `Character` object type is the "boxed" version of the `char` *base type*.

```
Character charObject  = (Character) 'c';
char charBase = (char) charObject;
```

actually, because of auto-boxing and auto-unboxing, you don't need the *explicit* cast:

```
Character charObject  = 'c';
char charBase = charObject;
```

However, a `String` is an object type much like any other object type. That means you cannot cast it to `char`, you need to use the [`charAt(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) method to retrieve characters from it.

Beware though that you may want to use [`codePointAt(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt-int-) instead, since Unicode code points may well extend out of the 65536 code points that can be stored in the 16 bits that a `char` represents. So please make sure that no characters defined in the "supplementary planes" are present in your string when using `charAt(int index)`.

As in Java any type can be converted to `String`, it is possibly to directly append characters to a string though, so `"strin" + 'g'` works fine. This is also because the `+` operator for `String` is syntactic sugar in Java (i.e. other objects cannot use `+` as operator, you would have to use a method such as `append()`). Do remember that it *returns a new string* rather than expanding the original `"strin"` string. Java strings are immutable after all.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, no, you cannot cast a single character `String` to a `char`. But you could extract it explicitly:

```
String message = "a";
char message1 = message.charAt(0);
```

Comment: why the two are incompatible to cast if they are storing the same one character?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast a String to a char. Below is a snippet to always pick the first character from the String,

```
char c = message.charAt(0);
```

In case you want to convert the String to a character array, then it can be done as,

```
String g = "test";
char[] c_arr = g.toCharArray(); // returns a length 4 char array ['t','e','s','t']
```

Answer (score 0):

A String with one char is more akin to a `char[1]`. Regardless, retrieve the character directly:

```
String ex = /* your string */;
if (!ex.isEmpty()) {
    char first = ex.charAt(0);
}
```